# jquery onblur text

Tags: jquery, text, blur

Сервисы

```
<div id="services_menu" class="hiddenmenu">
    <div class="framemenu">
        <div class="itemmenu"><a href="/flights_booking/" class="u" title="Покупка авиабилетов онлайн">Покупка авиабилетов онлайн</a></div>         
        <div class="itemmenu"><a href="/hotels/" class="u" title="Бронирование гостиниц онлайн">Бронирование гостиниц онлайн</a></div>          
        <div class="itemmenu"><a href="/sea_cruises_search/" class="u" title="Поиск круизов">Поиск круизов</a></div>            
        <div class="itemmenu"><a href="/flights_panel/" class="u" title="Табло аэропортов">Табло аэропортов</a></div>           
    </div>
</div>

$('.services').click(function() {
        $('#services_menu').attr('class') == 'hiddenmenu'  ?   $('#services_menu').attr('class', 'visiblemenu')    :   $('#services_menu').attr('class', 'hiddenmenu');
    });
```

It's okay.

But...How can I make by clicking on any place on the page, this field disappeared (class a **hiddenmenu**)

Sorry for bad english.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recently done something similar to this.

```
$('body').click(
  function(){
    // hide whatever
  }
);
```

Then for whatever you're hiding.

```
$('.services').click(
  function(e){
    // code
    e.stopPropagation(); // this stops the click event on the body from propagating.
  }
);
```

Comment: Everything works, but if you click on servises, then a body, then again on the services, it does not open anything

Comment: You'll have to make sure your click events are not conflicting. That is if you're body click event is hiding something needed in order for your services click event to fire.

Comment: If I click on any place on the page, then never doesn't open $('#services_menu')

Comment: Oh, sorry.
$('#services_menu').attr('class', 'hiddenmenu'); it's work, but hide() don't work

Comment: Are you still having trouble? If you are, post your code in something like jsbin.com, it'll make it easier for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $('.hiddenmenu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Isis   What about this?

```
  $(document).live('click', function(){
      $('.hiddenmenu').hide();
    });
```